# Files not showing in htdocs

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, http-status-code-404, htdocs

When creating a new database through `PHPMyAdmin` and trying to access `localhost/newdatabase`, I get this message:

> "Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If
>   you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.9"

The file doesn't show in `xampp/htdocs` either, only in `xampp/mysql/data`.
If i create files directly in htdocs, they work perfectly on localhost/.

Why has the file not been created in htdocs?

Answer (score 0):

The content of the htdocs folder are files that can be interpreted by the browser such as HTML5, CSS, JS, etc... in order to show a webpage along with it's funcionality to whoever accesses it. A database in the other hand can't directly be opened by a browser, but rather accessed within the server by a backend language like PHP, in order to get the information that can be stored in it through tables. You seem to be new to web programming, so I'd recommend to quickly google some beginner tutorials that can help you to understand the most important concepts. To take on from your kind of confusion, I'd point you to expand your knowledge on these concepts:

- HTML5
- CSS
- PHP
- MySQL

Once you get the grasp of them and identify each by their core funcionality, you'll be good on your way to make webpages. Later on you'll find yourself with demands like making your webpage look nice and clear, and also to make it load fast, but there's time for everything and the concepts I pointed are the best start for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna open your database URL = http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

File directory ~ xampp/htdocs for source code such as extension file .php .html .js or other.

if you wanna load localhost a URL is http://localhost:80 (auto find index file to first load)

Sample given as image folder for my code. Hope that can help you to understand xampp

[image]